# How long to soak white buckwheat?

Tags: food-preservation, raw, grains

I like to soak white buckwheat and do some raw recipes from it.

It is said that the optimal time for soaking is 1.5 days. I'm not changing the water
because of rutin preservation. What is the maximum
time it is eatable yet and why?

Now it's two days in the water and I wonder if tomorrow it will
be spoiled or some kind of bacteria in it.

Comment: Are you soaking in the fridge or on the counter?

Comment: @Stephie On the counter